# setenv() to update PATH environment variable

Tags: c, linux, setenv

i want to write a C program to append a string to PATH Environment variable.
something like  "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/mylib"

i have C code like this

setenv("PATH", "$PATH:$HOME/mylib",1);   **//which does not work.**

other work arround i thought was get PATH and HOME using getenv() and create a memory in heap then append them using strcat().

I might have to update PATH many times in my code: so this is a tiresome process.

is there any alternative?

Thanks

Comment: The good news is that you've got `setenv()`; if you had `putenv()`, life would be much harder — you'd almost inevitably leak memory.

Comment: I have created an example using setenv in other questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46400175/5842403

Answer (score 2):

The `$FOO` syntax, which expands to the value of the environment variable with the name `FOO`, is a feature of the shell; it's not directly available in C.

Your system may provide the [wordexp()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp) function, which gives you similar functionality in C.

But since you're just expanding two environment variables with fixed names (`"HOME"` and `"PATH"`), it makes more sense to use the portable `getenv()` function and a little string processing. (You might consider using `sprintf` or `snprintf` rather than `strcat`.)

NOTE: If you're only using the updated `$PATH` internally in your program, you can stop reading here.

Hopefully you're not expecting any changes to `$PATH` to be available on the command line after your program finishes running. Your running C program is most likely a child process of your interactive shell. Environment variables are inherited by child processes; they don't propagate back to parent proceses.

If that's what you're trying to do, you can have your program print the new `PATH` value to stdout, and then have the shell evaluate it:

```
PATH=`your-program`
```

Or it can print the command(s) to set one or more environment variables:

```
eval `your-program`
```

(In bash, you can use `$(your-program)` as well as `` `your-program` ``.)

Answer (score 1):

No there is no alternative. You have to build the literal string and pass it to setenv.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other option immediately available. You can write a separate function to handle this, if you need to do it several times.